# How to do autocomplete like IDE for my custom language on web?

Tags: javascript, xml, autocomplete, editor

I am try to make IDE on web ... My classes and it's fileds store in xml file ... I am using codemirror editor ... 
My question is :

I need to algorithm similar to one follow in IDE like (eclipse / visual studio) for autocomplete... in my language I have composition like any programming language for example (nameclass.fileds1.inner.  )... so can any body help me to find algorithm for do autocomplete for composition ?

NOTE : all my classes and it's fileds store in the xml file and codemirror can show me list to do autocomplete on it .... any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Well at a very basic level you just need to bind a key stroke event listener that looks up the current word being typed in the xml file to see if there are any matching options. Then take all the matching items and display them in a ul or something that will float next to the cursor.

If you want fast performance though you should think about building a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from all the xml options.

Here is some sample (pseudoish) code that ignores all the edge cases:

```
$('textarea.codepad').on('keyup paste', function() {
    var currentWord = $(this).val().split(' ').pop();
    var possibilities = getPossibilitiesFromXML(currentWord);
    displayPopup(possibilities);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help @Michaeldcooney